# How to rotate camera with constraint?

Tags: animation, camera, constraints

I use a follow path constraint to make the cam travel along a circle and I use a track to constraint to make the cam track to the object I want to render. That way I can control the camera very well but the problem is, that there is no way I can rotate the camera along the axis the camera is pointing to (see screenshot).

[image]

I tried:

- Rotating the circle
- Rotating the empty
- Rotating the cam

None of it does the trick.

I appreciate your help.

[image: Setup]
[image: Desired Rotation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible with a *Track To* constraint, so you could give the *Follow Path* and the *Track To* constraints to an empty, then parent the camera to this empty, the camera will be free to rotate:

[image]

Or give a *Damped Track* constraint to the camera:

[image]

Comment: thank you! the damped track worked perfectly for me.